# Java not working in self created private void, but on button action performed it does

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm quite new to java and on making my first GUI interface it ran into some difficulties and don't know how to search for a solution.

so in netbeans i created an interface with some buttons and a textfield. When i click on one of the buttons code is executed and a method is called, in this called method i tried changing the text of the textfield but it does not work, when i tried to change the textfield in a method (button actionperformed) which is created by netbeans and there is does work.

EDIT: Entire code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Creat new JFrame form.
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

//Decalre variables.
List<String> Expressions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

//I deleted the code that is automatically generated by netbeans here

```
//Button number 1.
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Call function to show expressions on screen.
    showExpressions("1");
}                                        

//Button 2 - 9 exactly the same as 1                    

//Button back.
private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   //Get the size of the list
   int size = Expressions.size();

   //Remove the last expression from the list
   Expressions.remove(size-1);

   //Show expressions in terminal.
   printExpressions();
}                                         

//Button plus.
private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //Add a comma to the string.
    addComma();

    //Call function to show expressions on screen.
    showExpressions("+");

    //Add a comma to the string.
    addComma();
}   

//Button minus the same as button plus.                                       

//button equal.
private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //Join the list
    String joined = String.join("",Expressions);

    //Split the list on a ','.
    String parts[] = joined.split("[\\,]");

    //Declare the outcome and operator.
    double outcome = 0;
    boolean operator = true;

    //Loop through all the parts.
    for (String part : parts) {

        //Check if part is a number or operator.
        if (part.equals("-") || part.equals("+")) {

            //part is an operator.
            switch (part) {
                case "+":
                    operator = true;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    operator = false;
                    break;
            }//Switch.

        } else {

            //Part is a number.
            if (operator)
                outcome += Double.valueOf(part);
            else
                outcome -= Double.valueOf(part);

        } //Try catch.

    }//Foreach.

    //Show outcome on screen
    System.out.println(outcome);

    //Clear the array.
    Expressions.clear();

}                                         

//showExpressions. (Add them to the list array.)
private void showExpressions(String value) { 

    Expressions.add(value); 
    System.out.println(Expressions);
}

//Add a comma before and after entering an operator, to split afterwards.
private void addComma() {
    Expressions.add(",");
}

//Show the expression in the terminal and on the screen.
private void printExpressions() {
    //Show the expression in the terminal.
    System.out.println(Expressions);
    jLabel1.setText("TESTTT");

    //Declare variables.
    String output = "";

    //Generate the numbers shown in the textfield
    for (String Expression : Expressions) {
        if (!Expression.equals("-") && !Expression.equals("+")) {
            output.concat(Expression);
        }//If.
    }//For.

    //Show in textfield on GUI.
    jTextField1.setText(output);

}

//Main static void.
public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

I also know 'show' is actually executed since in my project it also outputs in the terminal (which does work)

Comment: It should work, we'd need to see more of the code I think to understand why.  You might be doing something like just setting the wrong text field.  Can you show us more code?

Comment: Yess, i'll place more code, but i should set the right code, because when i copy the .setText() line exactly the same to the other method it works

Comment: And where is the actual error?  I see you are setting both `jLabel1` and `jTextField1` in `printExpressions`  Do either of those work?  Is that the method you are having trouble with?

Comment: I do not get any error, that's the problem, and no neither of these work, after the textfield didn't work i tried a label, but it got the same resutl, when i move the settext up to method of button1 action performed it does work..

Comment: Where do those 'action performed' methods get wired up to the buttons?

Comment: "Neither work"?  So does the `System.out.println(Expressions);` show anything on the screen?  Is its output correct?  You should also add a `println()` for the string `output` just before you set it, I'd like to see if that string is correct.

Comment: @DavidConrad It's the Netbeans GUI builder, it's done internally for you.  He probably just hasn't shown the code.  (On my system it's done inside `initiComponents()`.)

Comment: @markspace That may well be where the problem is, if OP modified that code.

Comment: I did not edit any of the auto generated code (editing is even disabled). I did print the expressions with system, and it shows the array.

Comment: I don't see any problems.  Maybe someone else can spot one.  We'll need the full source code including `Expression` so we can execute it to see what is the matter.  Note that you can't copy paste the GUI builder code, it hides stuff from you.  You'll need to use a separate editor to get the whole thing.

Comment: No problem, i'll try figuring something out and when i have i'll post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not an answer and I saw my question,
The problem has been resolved.

The problem being that the method that showed the value in the GUI was never called,
due to some typo if I remember correctly.